# AttributeError: read in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, python-requests

I'm trying to get an image then turn it into an object Python understands then upload.

This is what I have tried:

```
# Read the image using .count to get binary
image_binary = requests.get(
    "http://danealva143.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/2012-08-girls-920-26.jpg").content


string_buffer = io.BytesIO()
string_buffer.write(image_binary)
string_buffer.seek(0)

files = {}
files['image'] = Image.open(string_buffer)
payload = {}

results = requests.patch(url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/94/", data=payload, files=files)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 605, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot post a `PIL.Image` object; `requests` expects a file object.

If you are not altering the image, there is no point in loading the data into an `Image` object either. Just send the `image_binary` data instead:

```
files = {'image': image_binary}
results = requests.patch(url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/94/", data=payload, files=files)
```

You may want to include the mime-type for the image binary:

```
image_resp = requests.get(
    "http://danealva143.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/2012-08-girls-920-26.jpg")
files = {
    'image': (image_resp.url.rpartition('/')[-1], image_resp.content, image_resp.headers['Content-Type'])
}
```

If you actually wanted to manipulate the image, you'll first have to save the image back to a file object:

```
img = Image.open(string_buffer)
# do stuff with `img`

output = io.BytesIO()
img.save(output, format='JPEG')  # or another format
output.seek(0)

files = {
    'image': ('somefilename.jpg', output, 'image/jpeg'),
}
```

The [`Image.save()` method](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) takes an arbitrary file object to write to, but because there is no filename in that case to take the format from, you'll have to manually specify the image format to write. Pick from the [supported image formats](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

Comment: Just experimenting here, but what if i wanted to change the image. Would I need to turn it back into binary i.e. save it?

Comment: @Sputnik: added info on how to save back the PIL image to a `BytesIO` in-memory file object.